# How To group by a list of list and merge it into single list without repetition in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a class named studentdetails and a property named students which is the list of studentdetails.

```
public class studentdetails 
{
    public int SubjectId  {get ; set; }
    public int studentId  { get; set; } 
    public int ClassId  { get; set; }     
}

List<studentdetails> students = new List<studentdetails>()
{ 
    new studentdetails() { studentId = 1, SubjectId = 1, ClassId = 1 },
    new studentdetails() { studentId = 2, SubjectId = 2, ClassId = 1 },
    new studentdetails() { studentId = 3, SubjectId = 1, ClassId = 2 },
    new studentdetails() { studentId = 1, SubjectId = 3, ClassId = 2 },
    new studentdetails() { studentId = 1, SubjectId = 3, ClassId = 1 }
};
```

I have to create a list of class which contains list of student(which contains a list of sbject as property ) as a property without repeating class,student and subject if its already exist.

example:

```
public class Class
{
    public int ClassId  { get; set; }
    public Lits<student> students  { get; set; }
}
public class student
{
    public int StudentId  { get; set; }
    public Lits<Subject> subjects  { get; set; }
}
public class Subject 
{
    public int SubjectId   { get; set; }
}
```

For Example:
 With refer to above studentdetails

```
class(1) -student(1) -subject(1)
                     -subject(3)
         -student(2) -subject(2)

class(2) -student(3) -subject(1)
         -student(1) -subject(3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next approach can be used to solve the problem:

```
List<Class> classes = students
    // This GroupBy creates groups by ClassId:
    // (ClassId) -> (List of Students).
    .GroupBy(s => s.ClassId)
    .Select(c => new Class
    {
       ClassId = c.Key,
       Students = c
          // This GroupBy for given Class creates groups by StudentId:
          // (StudentId) -> (List of Subjects).
          .GroupBy(s => s.StudentId)
          .Select(s => new Student
          {
             StudentId = s.Key,
             Subjects = s
                // This GroupBy for given Class and Student removes
                // duplicate values of SubjectId. If you can guarantee
                // that for given Class and Student will not be duplicate
                // values of SubjectId then you can remove this GroupBy.
                // If you remove this GroupBy then you need to change 
                // expression inside Select to the following:
                // new Subject { SubjectId = t.SubjectId }.
                .GroupBy(t => t.SubjectId)
                .Select(t => new Subject { SubjectId = t.Key })
                .ToList()
          }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Here is [complete sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tKtFBH) that shows this approach.

---

@Thaks asked in the comment:

> If there is class name, student name and aсtivity name along with ids.
>   Then how can I map accordingly to the instance?

If you need additionally to map properties other then `id` then you should use the next overload of `GroupBy` method: [`GroupBy(keySelector, comparer)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___1__). Using this method we can use instances of `StudentDetails` class as keys and specify `comparer` for them.

At first we should create `comparer`, a class that implements interface [`IEqualityComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netcore-3.1). In our sample we can use a single `comparer` class to perform all three `GroupBy` operations, because all our `GroupBy` operations are performed using `int Id` property. Typically each `GroupBy` operation uses its own `comparer` class because most of the time different `GroupBy` operations are performed using different keys (different data types, different number of groupping properties). Here is how we can implement our `comparer`:

```
// For demo I simplified implementation of the Equals and GetHashCode
// methods by excluding null checks. In the documentation of 
// IEqualityComparer you can find implementation with null checks.
public class ComparerById<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, int> _keySelector;

    public ComparerById(Func<T, int> keySelector) => _keySelector = keySelector;

    public bool Equals(T x, T y) => _keySelector(x) == _keySelector(y);

    public int GetHashCode(T obj) => _keySelector(obj);
}
```

And then using this `comparer` we can perform required `GroupBy`:

```
List<Class> classes = students
    // Now key of each group has type StudentDetails, therefore later we
    // will be able to use properties of StudentDetails such as ClassName.
    // Here to compare keys of type StudentDetails we use comparer:
    // new ComparerById<StudentDetails>(s => s.ClassId);
    // It means that we create groups by ClassId.
    .GroupBy(s => s, new ComparerById<StudentDetails>(s => s.ClassId))
    .Select(c => new Class
    {
        ClassId = c.Key.ClassId,
        ClassName = c.Key.ClassName,
        Students = c
            // Here we create groups by StudentId.
            .GroupBy(s => s, new ComparerById<StudentDetails>(s => s.StudentId))
            .Select(s => new Student
            {
                StudentId = s.Key.StudentId,
                StudentName = s.Key.StudentName,
                Subjects = s
                    // Here we create groups by SubjectId.
                    .GroupBy(t => t, new ComparerById<StudentDetails>(t => t.SubjectId))
                    .Select(t => new Subject {SubjectId = t.Key.SubjectId, SubjectName = t.Key.SubjectName})
                    .ToList()
            }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Here is [complete sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L3iInE) that shows this approach.

Comment: if there is class name ,student name and ativity name along with ids .Then how can i map accordingly to the instance ?

Comment: @Thaks I updated my answer to include approach that can be used to map additional properties (class name, student name and etc.). Please, check it.

Comment: @lliar it is a good method. we can also get additional properties by directly using find method in the list with the key..