# Linq convert SQL response from one class to nested class output on group by .net core

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, nested

Got Response in object from SQL as below

[image: output]

Now want to have a fastest way to convert the data to nested class based on Floor, like below,

[image]

Created class structure like below,

[image]

Not sure how can I do group-by and make it enumerable, not sharing code as I want fresh/faster ideas.

Any reference link or sample code snippet will be helpful.

Comment: Floor class should have IEnumerable<Cafe> not IEnumrable<Floor>

Comment: right, corrected. Any approach you could share about making it nested in class?

Comment: Please, check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61440794/12833205. I think that your problem is the same and you can use the [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61458336/12833205) described in this link.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.  Buildings are grouped by BuildingId, and within each building group, the floors are grouped by FloorId.  Technically, the floor-grouping delegate returns a FloorHeader (which has 3 props: id, floor name, and floor code), but FloorHeader's Equality implementation only depends on the id.  The FloorHeader is just a means to include the name and code in the grouping (I assume floors with the same id also have the same name and code).

```
public readonly struct FloorHeader : IEquatable<FloorHeader> {
    public FloorHeader(int id, string name, int floorCode) {
        Id = id;
        Name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        FloorCode = floorCode;
    }

    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public int FloorCode { get; }

    public bool Equals(FloorHeader other) => other.Id == Id;
    public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is FloorHeader other && Equals(other);
    public override int GetHashCode() => Id;
}

public class Building {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Floor> Floors { get; set; }

    public class Floor {
        public FloorHeader Header { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Cafe> Cafes { get; set; }

        public class Cafe {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Label { get; set; }
            public double Area { get; set; }
        }
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<Building> ToBuildings(IEnumerable<Row> sql_reply) {
    // Equality of Building/FloorHeaders only depends on the id
    return sql_reply.GroupBy(row => row.BuildingId)
       .Select(building_rows =>
          new Building {
              Id = building_rows.Key,
              Floors = building_rows.GroupBy(row => new FloorHeader(row.FloorId, row.FloorName, row.FloorCode))
                .Select(floor_rows =>
                   new Building.Floor {
                       Header = floor_rows.Key,
                       Cafes = floor_rows.Select(cafe =>
                        new Building.Floor.Cafe {
                             Id = cafe.CafeId,
                             Label = cafe.CafeName,
                             Area = cafe.Area
                         })
                   })
          });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton John, that worked like charm, I am just finalizing the code.